# VBS apply Excel VBA macro to all files in current directory

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I try to apply a VBA macro kept in personl.xls to all files in a given directory,
but I hit an error in line 29..
I'm afraid I got things mixed up here:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Dim No_Of_Files
Dim i
Dim File_Path

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

File_Path = "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Eigene Dateien\Stuff\Test\"

With xlApp.FileSearch
  .NewSearch
  .LookIn = File_Path
  .Filename = "*.xls"
  .SearchSubFolders = False
  .Execute

  No_Of_Files = .FoundFiles.Count

  For i = 1 To No_Of_Files
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(i), 0, False) 
    xlApp.Run "'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Anwendungsdaten\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONL.XLS'!SASXLSFormat" 
    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
  Next i

End With

xlApp.Quit
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: What is line 29? And what does the error say?

Comment: It's the `next i`.  Message (in german): `Anweisungsende erwartet` (? en: Expect end of command ?)

Comment: @Kay - "Next i" isn't VBScript, use plain "Next".

Comment: If this is VBA as it appears then pls note `FileSearch` was deprecated in Office 2007. So for VBA you should either use `Dir` or the `FileScriptingObject` instead, for VBS use the `FileScriptingObject` as you did below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously was on a completedly wrong track.
But this seems to work properly:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Dim sPath

Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile

'make an object with the excel application 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Creating File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Getting the Folder Object
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Eigene Dateien\Stuff\Test")

'Getting the list of Files
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Running the macro on each file 
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    'MsgBox (ObjFolder & "\" & ObjFile.Name)
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ObjFolder & "\" & ObjFile.Name, 0, False) 
    xlApp.Run "'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Anwendungsdaten\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONL.XLS'!SASXLSFormat" 
    xlApp.xlBook.Close
Next

xlApp.Quit
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```